# how to install forever node module globally on windows machine?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, forever

I am trying to install node module "forever" globally on windows machine. So  tried installing it with "-g" switch

> C:\npm install -g forever

I specifically interested in file "forever.cmd". However this file gets install into the folder

> C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm

Well this is not truly global folder. Other users of the same machine cannot access this. Is there any other location forever module gets installed?

Comment: I believe that global doesn't mean system global, but user global in the case of NPM. Edit: I have been informed that I was wrong. Maybe check another users AppData to see if it's installed on every users files?

Comment: Have you tried running the command prompt as administrator? (Right-click -> "Run as administrator")

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a perfect solution for this issue.  You could re-install NodeJS, which includes NPM, but install it to a global folder like your system folder [(installation instructions here)](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows).  However, this will require administrator access which will make it potentially unsafe and a pain to use.

I would suggest just making a shortcut, alias, or adding the path to the environment variables for the user in question. That way when you do "forever start" in one user account you can do "forever list" in a different user account.

Good luck.

Comment: question was not about nodejs. The question was about npm modules, which are install with "-g" switch. I'm saying they are not truly global

Comment: Yes, when you install NodeJS, NPM (node package manager) is installed with it.  If you install NodeJS in a "truly global" location like C:\npm or your system folder then npm -g installations will also be "global".

Comment: Also `npm list -g --depth=0` will tell you where your global installs are located.  `npm get prefix` will tell you where you're saving packages and `npm set prefix {{new location}}` will let you change the location.  Personally, I'd just alias npm globals to other users to avoid impending file permission issues but you have many choices at your disposal.